# Creating tables with controllable values in PHP

Tags: php, nested-loops

Now i have the following:

```
    <?php include 'header.php'; ?>
    <body>


    <?php

    $rows_max    = 10;
    $columns_max = 10;

    $links = Array(
    'link' => "http://testlink.com",
    'image' => "img100x100.png");

    print '<table border="1px" style="border-collapse:collapse;">';
    for($row = 1; $row <= $rows_max; $row++) 
        {
        print '<tr>';
        for($col = 1; $col <= $columns_max; $col++)
            {
                print '<td width="100px" height="100px" background="'.$links["image"].'" >';
                                print '<a href="'.$links["link"].'"><center> </center></a>';
                //print "$row - $col";

                print '</td>';
            }
        print '</tr>';
        }

    print '</table>';

    include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

AND

```
td a
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0px auto;
}
```

All TD-s now link and have image, although they are all the same. How should i create backend so i can change all these data values individually? Thanks!

Comment: Use a database to keep the state of your changes from the backend and later display in the frontend. Nest your loops to create a 2D table.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
for ($tr=0; $tr<10; $tr++) {
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($td=0; $td<10; $td++) {
        echo "<td width=\"10\" height=\"10\">".$td."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this?

```
<?php
for($tr=0;$tr<=10;$tr++) 
{
    echo "<tr>";
    for($td=0;$td<=10;$td++) 
    {
    $image_link = "image_link";
    $image_path = "path/to/image.jpg";
    echo "<td width=\"10\" height=\"10\"><a href=\"{$image_link}\"><img src=\"{$image_path}\" /></a></td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Ahh, ofcourse, I'm dumb, started "for" with td, not tr :)

Answer (score -1):

That is a not bad start but, you will want to structure your code to be a nice as possible so when you want to change it you aren't straining your eyes to find the part to change.

```
<?php

$rows_max    = 10;
$columns_max = 10;

// Start Table
print '<table style="">';
for($row = 1; $row <= $rows_max; $row++) // Start at 1 instead of 0 to be nice
{
  print '<tr>';
  for($col = 1; $col <= $columns_max; $col++)
  {
    print '<td>';
    print "I am in row $row and column $col";
    print '</td>';
  }
  print '</tr>';
}
print '</table>';
```